# How to commit a project to TFS and SVN simultaneously?

Tags: svn, tfs

You may ask why do I need to commit a project to both?

In our firm, we had setup a system to backup all projects. We have used SVN for this purpose. Now we have a client, who is using TFS and the project is committed to their server. We want to keep a backup of the codes in our system too and we want to use the SVN server for that. We dont want to use a migrating tool.

So what I had planned was to use the TFS with the Visual Studio project and develop an AddIn/Plugin to commit to SVN server. But, that step hasn't been fruitful. Was not able to call the *DLLs* that can commit to SVN from the *AddIn* (I had used *SharpSVN*). Now I am trying to call SVN commands through code itself, using *System.Diagnostics.Process* . It also has encountered some issues.

I would like to get some suggestions on how to proceed. Should I go with the *AddIn* or Can I get the desired result through any other way? Or should we do this manually, like, copying the code and committing it to both TFS and SVN at the end of the day?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using SVN for all your other projects, I would personally stick with it for this project also.

As your client is using TFS, you can then use a post-commit hook script on your SVN server that will replicate changes on that specific project to their TFS server.

You can even work in an "*internal*" SVN branch of the code and replicate only changes that are merged to a "*published*" branch (that could be the trunk for example).

Comment: Ok. Thank you @Yannick Blondeau. Lemme look into it.

Comment: I tried Post-Commit. Smmes like it will do. But now I have encountered another problem. I am using VisualSVN server. and so when I commit a file, the cmd operations is not getting executed. if I use !#bh, it returns an error.

Comment: In your post-commit hook, you just have to call the command that will submit your change to TFS and then exit with `exit 0`...

Comment: It was some permission issue with VisualSVN server. I did as told here: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/visualsvn/v-VZYMl5kpI/nzIwnZ90cqEJ
and it was working fine. I could export the SVN codes and do other operations. Thank You @Yannick Blondeau